# Can use commands at cmd prompt but can't create a *.bat file with it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was successfully searching the web for a way to create a new folder containing ALL the .otf and .ttf files located in a different folder with subdirectories (one folder for each font, a total of 24 subfolders).

I used this:

```
for /r %x in (*.ttf, *.otf) do copy "%x" G:\dropbox\9mediendesignfachfrau\fonts\allezam\ /y
```

When I open cmd,

```
C:...>G:
G:...>cd \dropbox\9mediendesignfachfrau\fonts
G:...>for /r %x in (*.ttf, *.otf) do copy "%x" G:\dropbox\9mediendesignfachfrau\fonts\allezam\ /y
```

and enter, everything works fine.

I tried pasting that into a `.bat` file located in the `\fonts\` folder and tried starting it. `cmd` popped up and closed immediately, nothing else happened.

Could you help me finding my mistake?

It's still less work entering every line in `cmd`, press enter, enter the next line and so on than installing every single font manually but I'm quite lazy so I prefer a single double-click on a `.bat` file :P

Comment: In a batch file, `%x` must be changed to `%%x`.

Comment: You can actually read the help file for the FOR command it will literally answer your question.

Comment: Let me recommend to quote both source and destination paths, lke this: `copy /Y "[%]%~x" "G:\dropbox\9mediendesignfachfrau\fonts\allezam\"`; this avoids trouble with potential white-spaces and special characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use it in a batch file, the percent sign must be double,so,`%x` must be changed to `%%x` and your code looks like this :

```
@echo off
for /r %%x in (*.ttf, *.otf) do copy "%%x" G:\dropbox\9mediendesignfachfrau\fonts\allezam\ /y
pause
```

Comment: Da man from da command line: u rock Hackoo ... many applauses, God bless.